# array to typed object in TS

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have this array of string.

```
const check = [
    "AAA",
    "BBB",
];
```

How do I transform that to this object:

```
const check2 = {
    AAA: 111,
    BBB: 222
}
```

**I need** the solution to be intellisense friendly (i.e typed).

So far this is what I got:

```
const check = [
    "AAA",
    "BBB",
] as const;

type NAMES = typeof check[number];

const doSomething = () => 2;

const finalObj = Object.fromEntries(check.map((name: NAMES) => [name, doSomething()]));
```

But finalObj is not typed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get what you're trying to achieve with all that, but here's [a little playground here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwTAvDA2gIgIK8wGhkwCFSCiBhKzAXXghlEigG4AoNgek5gHEBTWAE8QAVxgATOFDgwoAC34wA7nCEwR41WFiKE-Nk2iSQAZRABbQfICWYAOaoYACgB07xPYgAuGKLAA1mAgymDoNACUqAB8RACMCTAgyBCW1nb2mOxsAGb%20wFA24PBIACogAPIARgBWADzYMPwAHlD8YBIM%20nAS4AA26tAIGeGEAEpOY-ygCBIN6GCiFlX8CDSEQxnR0c6ICL7YEb4TAN5sMBcw3DAAaquDNhYADn1KfSD2NsAwegaXMK9YCBasdpsk5psHBsoMMHLE0CcAL7sf45ZIuIywJQgHIlBBRM7-f7Amrofh0NC9cxWBQZZz8CIoy6I86XfRQUQIMBJWr0PyBYKhPljdgswzgYwkpx7crVGq7JCMrg8ACy-AgDGUNgUPJqP1WSigIDk6tgCkNQie6tcMAA6kpgHAwAByM2Ww2KGAANzgfVE6rk8jE9nkhH66nNMAC-CEEFcQA). It types the keys, not the values though (you can still try to set the value property of the `Record` type to the return type of `doSomething`)

Comment: Nice try, but in your exemple, values are all of a single same type. What I want is for them to be from any type, bottom line i think it needs to output a typed object and not a tuple nor record.

Comment: I can't help if I don't know what doSomething returns...

Comment: DoSomething is a function that can returns a string or number or a typed object.

Comment: Okay, then just use `Record<..., string | number | YourTypedObject>`... You won't be able to do better than that